# How to generate barcode checksum

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, checksum

I have a barcode with the characters; 34166110860346bNq (also see image below).
I would like to be able to:
1. identify what type of barcode it is and
2. what formula is used to generate it's checksum digits. (the last 3 digits are the checksum, bNq)

[image: image of barcode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the Code 128 barcode above in this snippet and the checksum generated is the integer 98. None of the trailing characters is part of the checksum. They will all be produced as scanned text by the scanner.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Plain Vanilla JS Code 128B Barcodes</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// The MIT License (MIT)
// Copyright (c) 2017, Notionovus, LLC.

var arrayCode128Bin = [ '11011001100', '11001101100', '11001100110', '10010011000', '10010001100', '10001001100', '10011001000', '10011000100', '10001100100', '11001001000', '11001000100', '11000100100', '10110011100', '10011011100', '10011001110', '10111001100', '10011101100', '10011100110', '11001110010', '11001011100', '11001001110', '11011100100', '11001110100', '11101101110', '11101001100', '11100101100', '11100100110', '11101100100', '11100110100', '11100110010', '11011011000', '11011000110', '11000110110', '10100011000', '10001011000', '10001000110', '10110001000', '10001101000', '10001100010', '11010001000', '11000101000', '11000100010', '10110111000', '10110001110', '10001101110', '10111011000', '10111000110', '10001110110', '11101110110', '11010001110', '11000101110', '11011101000', '11011100010', '11011101110', '11101011000', '11101000110', '11100010110', '11101101000', '11101100010', '11100011010', '11101111010', '11001000010', '11110001010', '10100110000', '10100001100', '10010110000', '10010000110', '10000101100', '10000100110', '10110010000', '10110000100', '10011010000', '10011000010', '10000110100', '10000110010', '11000010010', '11001010000', '11110111010', '11000010100', '10001111010', '10100111100', '10010111100', '10010011110', '10111100100', '10011110100', '10011110010', '11110100100', '11110010100', '11110010010', '11011011110', '11011110110', '11110110110', '10101111000', '10100011110', '10001011110', '10111101000', '10111100010', '11110101000', '11110100010', '10111011110', '10111101110', '11101011110', '11110101110', '11010000100', '11010010000', '11010011100', '1100011101011', '11010111000'];
var array5bit_A = [ 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'SL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'];
var array5bit_B = [ 'US0CAuSD38g', 'UUYCA7QBErs', 'ajEDAm49ReY', 'UUoCA+juogg', 'bjEDAjQrOn0', 'bkoDA3iPVH4', 'ajUDAt82atY', 'UU4CA1nljTg', 'cjEDAghkmFU', 'ckoDA0TA9lY', 'izUEAhrxcbg', 'ck4DAxY8F10', 'bjUDAlvFFR8', 'bk4DAxdhexw', 'ajkDAr7LFAw', 'UVICAyQ+UJI', 'TTECAq7UnEM', 'TUoCA+Jw8kA', 'ZjUDAmZGozo', 'TU4CA7CME0s', 'ajUDAvnk9E4', 'ak4DA7VAmk0', 'ZjkDAtle3bI', 'TVICAxOyzrM', 'STUCAqHeHtM', 'SU4CA+16cNA', 'h6QEAZKdo54', 'SVICA62zYxM', 'RTkCAqx1lb4', 'RVICA/z3WM0', 'QT0CAkdoxRU', 'KFYBA46vJCA'];
var stringStart = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/A';
var stringMid = 'AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
var stringEnd = 'AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:';

function genBarcode(inputString, intWidth, intHeight) {
var arraySeq = [], i, intChunks, resultString;
var intRawmod = inputString.length % 5;
  for (i = 0; i < 5 - intRawmod; i += 1) {
    inputString += "0";
  }
  intChunks = inputString.length / 5;
  for (i = 0; i < intChunks; i += 1) {
    arraySeq[i] = parseInt(inputString.substr(i * 5, 5), 2);
  }
  resultString = "";
  for (i = 0; i < arraySeq.length; i += 1) {
    resultString += stringStart + array5bit_A[arraySeq[i]] + stringMid + array5bit_B[arraySeq[i]] + stringEnd + intWidth + 'px;height:' + intHeight + 'px;">';
  }
  return resultString;
}

function funcCode128C(strText) {
  'use strict';
let i, j, intWeight, intLength, intWtProd = 0;
let arrayData = [];
let strRaw = [];

 intLength = strText.length;
 intWtProd = arrayData[0] = 105; // Start with Code 128C
 console.log(`Value ${arrayData[0]}, Multiplier 1, Cumulative ${intWtProd}`);
 for (i = 0, j = 0; i < intLength; i += 2, j += 1) {
   arrayData[j + 1] = parseInt(strText.substr(i, 2), 10);
   intWeight = j + 1;
   intWtProd += intWeight * arrayData[j + 1];
     console.log(`Value ${arrayData[j + 1]}, Multiplier ${j + 1}, Cumulative ${intWtProd}`);
 }
 arrayData[++j] = 100; // Switch to Code 128B
   intWtProd += j * arrayData[j];
     console.log(`Value ${arrayData[j]}, Multiplier ${j}, Cumulative ${intWtProd}`);
 arrayData[++j] = 66; // Lowercase 'b'
   intWtProd += j * arrayData[j];
     console.log(`Value ${arrayData[j]}, Multiplier ${j}, Cumulative ${intWtProd}`);
 arrayData[++j] = 46; // Uppercase 'N'
   intWtProd += j * arrayData[j];
     console.log(`Value ${arrayData[j]}, Multiplier ${j}, Cumulative ${intWtProd}`);
 arrayData[++j] = 81; // Lowercase 'q'
   intWtProd += j * arrayData[j];
     console.log(`Value ${arrayData[j]}, Multiplier ${j}, Cumulative ${intWtProd}`);
 arrayData[++j] = intWtProd % 103; // Checksum will be the integer 98 for this example
 console.log("Checksum = ", arrayData[j]);
 arrayData[++j] = 106;
 strRaw = "";
 for (i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i += 1) {
  strRaw += arrayCode128Bin[arrayData[i]];
 }
 return strRaw;
} // End Code 128C

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128C("34166110860346"), 18.3, 50);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are curious about how to calculate the checksum, add up the "characters" multiplied by their weighted sum as they appear in the Code 128C/B chart [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_128#Bar_code_widths) and then get the remainder of the number divided by 103. I have logged the process to the console.

Comment: Thanks. 
are you saying bNq is note part of the barcode? 
the manual I had, said bNq is the checksum that is generated. But the manual didnt say how to generate this checksum(bNq) so I was wondering if anyone knows how to do that.

Comment: 'bNq' is data embedded in the barcode. So, it is not the barcode's checksum. According to your manual, it is a checksum generated for the number "34166110860346". If the system reading the number requires a check for that number's authenticity, then it will use 'bNq' in an algorithm to verify. It would be nearly impossible with any degree of certainty to reverse-engineer that application-level algorithm with only one data point.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it with the hardware of the barcode reader.
Most barcode readers have the option to notify letters indicating barcode type.
Please refer to the manual of the barcode reader to use.

The check digit calculation method is different depending on each barcode type. Also, the presence/absence of a check digit and the presence/absence of a check digit notification to an application are determined depending on the barcode type. However, there are cases where the option is decided by the user.

If you want to know them, please refer to the standard documents such as ISO.